# What would cause an LCD panel to get both slightly dim and slightly blurry?

Tags: lcd

I just tested an old W530 Thinkpad laptop with a [B156HTN01.1](http://www.panelook.com/B156HTN01.1_AUO_15.6_LCM_parameter_20471.html) LCD panel, which is supposed to be [identical or better in every spec](http://www.panelook.com/modelcompare.php?ids=686,20471) to my other old T520 Thinkpad's [B156HW01 V4](http://www.panelook.com/B156HW01%20V4_AUO_15.6_LCM_parameter_686.html) panel. However, compared to the v4 at max brightness, the N01.1 is a bit dimmer, a tiny bit blurrier (hard to pin down or describe, but very annoying over time), and you can easily see the pixel grid from a distance (on the v4 you have to look close and concentrate to see the pixels at any brightness).

I am curious as to what would cause a panel to fail in this way. My guess would be the backlight, which is only rated to 10K hours, but I would think that would only explain the dimness and possibly the pixel grid. What could explain the very slight blurriness or fuzziness?

Notes:

- I am pretty sure the issues are not related to software drivers or calibration. I used a color calibrator, and I tested using 3 different OS's. Resolution is correct at 1920x1080, and I tried various DPI and anti-aliasing/ sub-pixel smoothing settings.
- The blurriness is slight enough that I keep thinking "it is my imagination", except that I am constantly "re-imagining" that it is causing me eye strain. Perhaps it is the more pronounced pixel grid or a dullness of certain of the component lights relative to others? How can I find out more?

Test 1 - I switched the panels on the two laptops.

- The N01.1 still has a more visible grid, but it is now almost (but not quite) as bright as the v4 and maybe a bit sharper than before. The v4 seems not quite as sharp now. But that may be my imagination.
- The system clock is off at bootup on the W530 (which now has the v4). Could that have something to do with it?

Test 2 - I ordered a new N01.1 LCD panel and another used W530. When those arrived, I compared the faulty panel to the brand new N01.1 panel on the different W530 laptop, and there is not much difference in sharpness. My conclusions:

- The display connector must have been loose before I switched the panels, and that caused some blurriness and/or dimness.
- The N01.1 panel is not as good (to my eyes?) as the v4, despite what the specs say.

Comment: Other than a bad/jittery clock somewhere causing the LCD driver to read either an earlier or later pixel in the datastream (so some parts of the image get shifted one pixel sometimes) or some incorrectly configured timings (maybe it wasn't quite as advertised?) I can't think of much that'd cause an LCD to be fuzzy (unless it was defective from the start).

Comment: @Sam Would switching the good panel with the bad panel rule any of these out? Or is the clock/ timings built into the panel?

Comment: Most modern displays have the ability to tell the computer what their desired resolution and timings are so the data should be in the panel to some degree, but that doesn't ensure the computer will always pick the right one (e.g. I've got an 800x480 LCD that presents itself as a 1920x1080 panel when hooked up to my main pc, but appears as an 800x480 panel on my linux box). On the other hand it could be something simple like a bad connection somewhere, maybe the display cable just needs re-seating? But try the old panel anyway just to try and rule out a hardware fault on the computer side.

Comment: @Sam I switched the panels on the two laptops - see updates in post. You mentioned a bad clock. I will try switching or replacing the CMOS battery. Any other hardware I should try replacing? Resolution is correct to spec (1920x1080). How do I check if the timing was detected correctly in Linux?

Comment: I would think the power-supply connection might be a bit dodgy.  If the power supply voltage fluctuates some based upon what is displayed, and the contrast of a line depends upon the supply voltage during the part of the frame when it is displayed, that could cause the contrast of each line to depend upon what was displayed on the line above, causing some blurriness.

Comment: By "clock" I meant the pixel clock that drives the display, it's the clock responsible for telling the panel when to sample the pixel data, a jittery pixel clock means that the panel might sample the wrong pixels sometimes (but it'd only jump out of sync by a single pixel I'd imagine). Sorry if I didn't clarify it enough before. I don't know how to check if your panel's using the correct timings, there's a way to display the selected timings, but unless you know what they *should* be, it's anyone's guess. Is everything fuzzy or just text? (if so, "cleartype" or something similar might be on)

Comment: @supercat Thanks for the suggestion. I ordered another used FHD W530 and a new N01.1 LCD panel. When those arrive, I'll see if switching the power supply between the two laptops does anything.

Comment: @Sam Thanks for the info! The panel specs are linked to in the post. Are any of those the "timing"? And no, it is not just the fonts. I already tried multiple settings for DPI and anti-aliasing/ sub-pixel smoothing.

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusions are interesting. If I ignore your imagination caveat, one (perhaps too obvious) cause would be some kind of aftermarket filter/protector applied to the screen. I've seen this before, and it was quite difficult to see the filter unless you get right to the edge, particularly if it was applied professionally. It wouldn't surprise me on a thinkpad.

Comment: This is interesting. To clarify: are you saying that the v4 may have had a filter applied that makes it a better panel than when it was first manufactured?

Comment: That's also interesting but actually, the opposite, I was suggesting the N01.1 may have had some coating (they can be liquid) or otherwise applied. I would have commented, but I don't currently have sufficient rep. [Here] (https://www.amazon.ca/Protector-Thinkpad-Oleophobic-Coating-Healing/dp/B01MCTMFRY/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1484376045&sr=8-1&keywords=laptop+screen+coating+thinkpad) is a link to something close to what I'm suggesting. There are a pile of variations, and I'm guessing some of them don't age well.

Comment: I would also check colour profiles as best you can. I personally use flux and find the slightly yellow evening tint to be pleasant, but also oddly blurrier. If you have photos or video, that might be helpful (or a screenshot, which (I think) would rule out software issues). At this point I'm just guessing though.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot idea; that is a good thing to compare to the external photos. I can't see any coatings, but maybe I'm just not recognizing them.