# How to objectively test LCD for very slight "blurriness" (and prove it is not just my imagination)?

Tags: lcd, diagnostic, measurement

In [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1165759/what-would-cause-an-lcd-panel-to-get-both-slightly-dim-and-slightly-blurry), I keep "re-imagining" that the LCD panel is slightly blurry or causing me eye strain.

The cause might be a tiny deviation in any number of things: voltage, timing, dithering, uneven backlight, etc....

Is there a way to inexpensively (`<$100` or so), objectively (with numbers?) test for slight visual problems with an LCD display and prove to myself it is not just my imagination and help narrow down the problem? Maybe some sort of test equipment?

For example, when I switched the LCD displays on the two laptops in [that  question](https://superuser.com/questions/1165759/what-would-cause-an-lcd-panel-to-get-both-slightly-dim-and-slightly-blurry), it seemed to have improved the sharpness on one panel and reduced it in the other - but after staring at these displays for so many hours, how can I be sure it's not just my memory that is blurry? And even if it did change the sharpness - how do I know which quality it affected (since the problem is so subtle)?

**What I already tried:**

- Resting my eyes. But the problem is so subtle, this does not help.
- Using [the test images](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/). The test results were not vastly different between the two LCD displays, even when the problem was obvious (before the switch). And what if I did not have a second panel to compare the results to?
- Best so far: As suggested by fixer1234, I took [closeup photographs](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMcp3eb5a7xAVAVUfmZLozORIp8TBsLcnMoiXLnCuqkbei0BfEF26aF7RqmqMt9Hg?key=aVdoWjk1N1BjWmNoaDFkazlyR25rQnp0LXpnRkR3) of the same image on multiple LCDs. This really shows some interesting differences (and similarities) between the displays!

  - The only shortcoming of the photo method is that it does not show how things change over time. For example: an occasional shifted pixel, or temporal dithering. A high-resolution/ high frame-rate video camera would of course solve this, but I wonder if there is a more economical option?
  - A [tip from Gryph](https://superuser.com/a/1167159/209118): also take a screenshot, which can be compared with the external photos to rule out software issues.

Comment: If you've been staring at something for many hours the correct approach would be to take a break and relax your eyes. An inexpensive way would be to ask friends or co-workers for their opinion on whenever they see a difference. If you still do have trouble with that display (even if it is just subjective) just exchange it.

Comment: @Seth Thanks, but I am hoping for something more quantitative. Maybe some sort of testing equipment?

Comment: Take a high-resolution photo of the screen where you think it's blurry.  Look at that image at its native resolution, which should appear magnified on the screen.  You'll be able to see the detail of exactly what you're looking at.  You should be able to see whether or not it is actually blurry, and what might be giving that impression.

Comment: @fixer1234 That's a great idea! I will do that with both text and images. Thanks!

Comment: @fixer1234 Worked great, thanks! But see what I wrote about it in the post.

Comment: A more economical option: a really, really cheap high-resolution, high frame rate video camera?  :-)   I'll have to cogitate on this one.

Answer (score 1):

For quick, cheap and easy, get some test patterns.  They are definitely the way to go when comparing 'a' and 'b'.  Here is one [source](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/).  This is still subjective, but it is cheap.

Comment: Yes, I already tried these. I am looking for something even more objective :)